# Mysql order by from 2 joined tables very slow with filesort and temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I can't figure out how to optimize this query and get rid of the temporary table and filesort. I have tried adding so many indexes with no luck that I have stripped them all off for this question because I really do not know where to start.

My question is, how do I optimize this query as much as possible if I am not able to change the table structure or the data other than adding indexes. I can change the query itself. Each table holds about 10,000 records and it will double in size in about a month but stay at that size for the foreseeable future.

Below I will include the table structure as well as the query I am trying to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `area` (
  `id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `boardid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `val` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `prikey` (`id`,`boardid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subarea` (
  `id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `boardid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `val` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `prikey` (`id`,`boardid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `area_relations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `boardid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `areaid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `subareaid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE me.id, me.areaid, me.subareaid, me.boardid
  FROM database1.area_relations me
  JOIN database1.area area
    ON area.boardid = me.boardid AND area.id = me.areaid
  JOIN database1.subarea subarea
    ON subarea.boardid = me.boardid AND subarea.id = me.subareaid
WHERE me.boardid = '120' ORDER BY area.val, subarea.val
```

I really appreciate any help with this and have tried RTFMing on joins, indexes, filesort, etc, but am hitting a wall.

Here are the explain results.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  me  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6222    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  area    ref     prikey  prikey  96  database1.me.areaid,const       1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  subarea     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7409    Using where
```

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Are you sure this query plan is for the table structure you posted? Also can you make a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) which reproduces it?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the following index on `area_relations`:

```
create index idx_area_relations_board_id_id on area_relations(board_id, id)
```

This will allow the `where` clause to use filtering.

You are stuck with the filesort, because you are ordering by columns from multiple tables.

Comment: A board_id index will help but I think the main problem is the non-indexed JOIN (subarea).